# How to use laravel application as both web application and Rest API

Tags: laravel, flutter, vue.js

I am implementing a laravel web application and I separately implementing a native mobile application as well. I need to use the same backend which I use for a web application for mobile application as well. How can I implement the backend as a REST API which can be called from a mobile application and also use for the web application as well?

Comment: it's simple! just make your API's  and then call them with both Vue (for web) and flutter(for mobile). you dont need to specify them for seprate usage!

Answer (score 2):

there's a file located in `routes/api.php`.
You can store your API there like the way you implement your routes at `web.php`. But **return JSON** from your controller for your **REST API**.

you can call it like `http://yourdomain/api/yourroute`

Comment: do you have any example or tutorial, can you share the link of that please.

Comment: https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/laravel-basic-api-routes/

@lordyhas this maybe the most basic i can found on internet. hope it helps